# How to implement jQuery DataTable in asp.net 3.5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

First time going to implement the jQuery DataTable in asp.net with a aspx page webmethod, here is the webmethod code,

```
    [WebMethod()]
    public static List<Activity> GetJobActivity(int jobid)
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            DataTable DT = new DataTable();
            List<Activity> activity = new List<Activity>();
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = Con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "SP_GetJobActivity";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@jobid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = jobid;
                Con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DA.Fill(DT);
                foreach (DataRow DR in DT.Rows)
                {
                    Activity act = new Activity();
                    act.comment = DR["Comment"].ToString();
                    act.activity = DR["activity"].ToString();
                    act.emp = DR["EmpName"].ToString();
                    act.createdon = DR["Createdon"].ToString();
                    activity.Add(act);
                }
            }
            Con.Close();
            return activity;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new System.Exception("Error In Get Job Activity :" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I tried to get the data using jquery ajax function with Post method like

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ViewJob.aspx/GetJobActivity",
            data: JSON.stringify({ jobid: $("#id").val()}),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                RenderTable(response.d);
            }
        });
```

but its not working, please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Could give more info on "its not working"

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dataTable'

Comment: This error raised on which line ?